# (Angular) Share Data between components with Two-way Data Binding vs Services

Tags: angular, data-binding, service, two-way-binding

I want to have a parent component with two child components. The child components both need the same information and they need to be consistent. Should I create a variable in the parent component and pass it onto the child components via two-way data binding (so that changes to either child will propagate to the parent and then to the other child) or via a service?

I'm not sure how to do it with a service either. I read up on something called a Subject. Would that be the direction to go into if I wanted to maintain consistent data between two components?

I currently have a single parent component and a child component. I pass on the data from parent to child through one-way data binding and the child component sends a HTTP request to modify my data. These changes are not being reflected in my parent component, but I am considering using two-way data binding to get the changes reflected in the parent. However, I also plan to make a portion of the parent component into another child component, and I'm not sure if using data binding is the best way to move forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try answering your question (if I understood it right).
Understand the difference when you should use the input/output vs. services for data sharing-

You can achieve the same functionality using both of the approaches, but you should always consider the following points before achieving your functionality-

**When to use input/output-**

- If you have small scale application,
- If you want to share data between only few components,
- There is parent-child relationship between components.

**When to use services-**

- If you are dealing with large application, and you don't want to mess up the communication between components by sharing so many variables among different components.
- There is no parent child relationship between components.
- Data is coming from servers and you just sharing among different components

Then you can go ahead, and write getter and setter method to share data from those service. Or can emit the values using observables and subscribes it in you components.

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helps.

Comment: If it helped, then please upvote and mark this answer as well.